# How To Create Clothing Items Model - Different Sizes for Shoes, Shirts, Jeans ect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating an online retail store.

Just wondering how some of you professionals would go about creating a Clothes Model.

**Problem**
Shoes have different sizes like mens 8,9,10,12 ect. Shirts have 38,40,42 chest. Jeans have 32, 34,36. Dresses have size 6, 8 ect.

How would someone go about making an clothing items model. So when someone creates and item, they first click on which category they want. Lets say Shoes, then it brings down a list of shoe sizes and you can then put in the quantity for each shoe size you have and all other attributes like price and ect.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to provide assistance with *specific programming questions* as opposed to providing a design guidance. You'd be best served by reviewing the principles of object oriented design at this point, paying attention to the terms "inheritance," "composition" and "aggregation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Polymorphic Associations for the solution you are looking for. For your case you can create your models as shown below

```
    # Your Models
    class CommonSize < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :common_sizable, :polymorphic => true
    end

    class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :common_sizes, :as => :common_sizable
    end

    class Dress < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :common_sizes, :as => :common_sizable
    end

    class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :common_sizes, :as => :common_sizable
    end

    # Your controllers
    # shoes_controller
    def create
      shoe = Shoe.new(...)
      shoe.common_size.build(...)
      shoe.save
    end
    # Similarly create other controllers
```

For clearly understanding polymorphic associations in rails, you can see the video http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Calling the model as `CommonSize` instead of `size` because `size` belongs to Ruby Enumerator class.

Answer (score 0):

Go for polymorphic associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html